# Using Boost::Python::Object causes linker errors

Tags: c++, boost, scripting, boost-python, python-embedding

So, I'm attempting to embed Python into C++. I have gotten fairly far in, and have been able to do basic things like run strings of Python. As soon as I tried to use Boost::Python::Object I began getting these 4 linker errors.

I built boost using BJAM with Boost 1.54.0 and Python 2.7.5.

**Python Lib Build Commands:**

```
bootstrap
.\b2 toolset=msvc-10.0 --with-python
```

**Minimal Code Example :**

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char **) 
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import Entity");

    boost::python::object main_module = boost::python::import("__main__");
    boost::python::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

    Py_Finalize();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**Linker Errors:**

```
1>PythonTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::import(class boost::python::str)" (__imp_?import@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@api@12@Vstr@12@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>PythonTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: __thiscall boost::python::detail::str_base::str_base(char const *)" (__imp_??0str_base@detail@python@boost@@IAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::python::str::str(char const *)" (??0str@python@boost@@QAE@PBD@Z)
1>E:\Dev\PythonTest\Debug\PythonTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Verify that `PythonTest.exe` is being linked against the Boost.Python library.  Also, you do **not** want to call `Py_Finalize()` when using Boost.Python.

Comment: I double-checked and I am linking against boost python. May I ask why I should not use Py_Finalize()? What does it cause?

Comment: Boost.Python does not support safely calling `Py_Finalize()`.  In short, some internal Boost.Python objects will remain alive during `Py_Finalize()`, and only attempt to be deleted when Boost.Python unloads, causing the objects to attempt deletion with a non-existent interpreter.  It is noted in the [Embedding - Getting Started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/embedding.html) section, and listed in the [TODO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/todo.html#pyfinalize-safety).

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I'm still getting these errors.

Comment: The symbol visibility look as though `PythonTest` is expecting the Boost.Python library to have been built for dynamic linking.  It may be worth checking symbol visibility within the built Boost.Python library.  If the symbols are not exported, then try to build for the static library by defining `BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB` when either building `PythonTest` or before including `boost/python.hpp`.

Comment: Tanner, that actually does work. I got it working last night with that. I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Boost.Python can be built for static or dynamic linking.  This is controlled by `BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB` being defined or not defined during the build process.  The [boost mailing list](http://www.google.com/search?q=boost_python_static_lib+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Flists.boost.org) seems to indicate that this defintion and built-types are the result of some confusion.

When `BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB` is not defined, then Boost.Python assumes dynamic linkage.  As a result, Boost.Python decorates symbol visibility for [dllimport and dllexport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  Based on the linker error, the example code was expecting to import the `boost::python::import()` function during linkage.  If you have verified that the Boost.Python library is being linked, then the problem is likely the result of Boost.Python being built for static linkage, where the functions are not decorated for exporting.  To resolve this, do one of the following:

- Build Boost.Python for dynamic linkage (i.e. make sure `BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB` is not defined).
- Define `BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB` when building the example code.
- Define `BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB` in the example code *before* including `boost/python.hpp`.