# Boost Python class export fails to compile with linking error in visual studio 2013

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I compiled Boost myself and used it to export the following function to a DLL :

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

std::string greet()
{
    return "hello, dude !!";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

This loaded fine in Python after I renamed the hello.dll file to hello.pyd.

Now I am trying this :

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

struct World
{
    void set(std::string msg) { this->msg = msg; }
    std::string greet() { return msg; }
    std::string msg;
};


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    class_<World>("World")
        .def("greet", &World::greet)
        .def("set", &World::set);
}
```

It errors out with :

```
Error   29  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void * __cdecl boost::python::objects::find_static_type(void *,struct boost::python::type_info,struct boost::python::type_info)" (__imp_?find_static_type@objects@python@boost@@YAPAXPAXUtype_info@23@1@Z) referenced in function "private: virtual void * __thiscall boost::python::objects::value_holder<struct World>::holds(struct boost::python::type_info,bool)" (?holds@?$value_holder@UWorld@@@objects@python@boost@@EAEPAXUtype_info@34@_N@Z) D:\Code\Python\hello\hello\hello.obj    hello

Error   30  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall boost::python::converter::shared_ptr_deleter::shared_ptr_deleter(struct boost::python::converter::shared_ptr_deleter const &)" (__imp_??0shared_ptr_deleter@converter@python@boost@@QAE@ABU0123@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::shared_ptr<void>::shared_ptr<void><void,struct boost::python::converter::shared_ptr_deleter>(void *,struct boost::python::converter::shared_ptr_deleter)" (??$?0XUshared_ptr_deleter@converter@python@boost@@@?$shared_ptr@X@boost@@QAE@PAXUshared_ptr_deleter@converter@python@1@@Z) D:\Code\Python\hello\hello\hello.obj    hello

Error   31  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall boost::python::objects::class_base::~class_base(void)" (__imp_??1class_base@objects@python@boost@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0?$class_@UWorld@@Unot_specified@detail@python@boost@@U2345@U2345@@python@boost@@QAE@PBD0@Z$0    D:\Code\Python\hello\hello\hello.obj    hello

Error   32  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl boost::python::objects::register_dynamic_id_aux(struct boost::python::type_info,struct std::pair<void *,struct boost::python::type_info> (__cdecl*)(void *))" (__imp_?register_dynamic_id_aux@objects@python@boost@@YAXUtype_info@23@P6A?AU?$pair@PAXUtype_info@python@boost@@@std@@PAX@Z@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::python::objects::register_dynamic_id<struct World>(struct World *)" (??$register_dynamic_id@UWorld@@@objects@python@boost@@YAXPAUWorld@@@Z)  D:\Code\Python\hello\hello\hello.obj    hello
```

This is Visual Studio Express 2013. I compiled my own boost libraries following the exact steps as given here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html

I think my build/installation is fine as the global function before this was fine. But maybe there is some incompatibility with MSVC 2012 and 13 because the boost python debug library is named `boost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_56.lib`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the answer at:
[Using Boost::Python::Object causes linker errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058374/using-boostpythonobject-causes-linker-errors?rq=1)

As bjam compiles boost for static linking using the steps given at : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html

I need to define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB or it will assume dynamic linkage for the Boost.python library.

Code that compiles:

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB    
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;


struct World
{
    void set(std::string msg) { this->msg = msg; }
    std::string greet() { return msg; }
    std::string msg;
};


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    class_<World>("World")
        .def("greet", &World::greet)
        .def("set", &World::set);
}
```

*One way* to use hello.dll, is to first rename hello.dll to hello.pyd and copy it to the directory where Python.exe starts from, then :

Python code :

```
import hello
obj = hello.World()
obj.set("Hello World!")
obj.greet()
```