# Boost.Python Quickstart Linker Errors

Tags: python, c++, visual-c++, boost, boost-python

I'm just trying to follow the instructions [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/building.html) to get the Quickstart example working. I am on Windows 7 and trying to use MSVC. I have Python 2.7 installed.

What I have done:

- Download boost_1_57_0.zip and extract to `C:\boost_1_57_0`.
- From command prompt in `C:\boost_1_57_0`, run:

  ```
  bootstrap
  ```

  then:

  ```
  .\b2
  ```

  as per the instructions under 5.1 [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/windows.html). After this I have a message saying "The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!".
- Add `C:\boost_1_57_0` to my path. The instructions don't say to do this, but since they want me to invoke bjam, and that's where it lives, I assume I need to do this.
- Modify `C:\boost_1_57_0\libs\python\example\quickstart\boost-build.jam` so that the path is `boost-build ../../../../tools/build/src ;` and not `boost-build ../../../../tools/build/v2 ;`. This is as per the instructions [here](http://lists.boost.org/boost-build/2014/11/27738.php) since the original path is wrong and if you don't do this the bjam invocation fails.
- CD into `C:\boost_1_57_0\libs\python\example\quickstart` and run:

  ```
  bjam toolset=msvc --verbose-test test
  ```

The output I get is firstly:

```
...patience...
...patience...
...found 1926 targets...
...updating 55 targets...
common.mkdir bin
common.mkdir bin\test_ext.test
common.mkdir bin\test_ext.test\msvc-12.0
common.mkdir bin\test_ext.test\msvc-12.0\debug
common.mkdir bin\test_ext.test\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi
common.mkdir bin\msvc-12.0
common.mkdir bin\msvc-12.0\debug
common.mkdir bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi
compile-c-c++ bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.obj
extending.cpp
c:\python27\include\pymath.h(22) : warning C4273: 'round' : inconsistent dll linkage
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(516) : see previous definition of 'round'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xtgmath.h(190) : warning C4273: '_hypot' : inconsistent dll linkage
```

followed by a long list of other header file entries, each complaining about inconsistent dll linkage, and then at the end a bunch of errors, highlights of which include:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1207: incompatible PDB format in 'C:\boost_1_57_0\libs\python\example\quickstart\bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.pdb'; delete and rebuild

...failed msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.pyd bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.pdb...
...removing bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.pdb

LINK : warning LNK4001: no object files specified; libraries used
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
bin\test_embed.test\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\test_embed.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

...failed msvc.link bin\test_embed.test\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\test_embed.exe bin\test_embed.test\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\test_embed.pdb...
...removing bin\test_embed.test\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\test_embed.pdb
...skipped <pbin\test_embed.test\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi>test_embed.run for lack of <pbin\test_embed.test\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi>test_embed.exe...
...failed updating 4 targets...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also saw that incompatible PDB format issue, but only with 1.57, which (since the Boost.Python source is the same for 1.57 and 1.55 and I can get it working on 1.55) I'm guessing is somehow related to the changes in the boost::build path.

I've [documented what I had to do](https://gist.github.com/teeks99/bb4921dffc8a74423c26#file-boost-python-quickstart-md) to get it working with 1.55, maybe that will be some help.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I had to leave this and haven't tried again for months, but now I've followed the instructions linked and it appears to work. For anyone else: it appears the easiest thing to do is use 1.55, since 1.56 and above have the pdb format problem. Also, I don't think I'd set up the user-config.jam as you suggest. BTW, you have a typo in the user-config.jam on your blog - you've mis-spelt 'python' here: "C:\\Pyhton27-32\\libs  # link libs".

Comment: I've updated the gist, thanks for pointing out that error. Also 1.59 is out next week, I'm hoping this will be fixed then.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is still present with 1.59. I've managed to get Boost.Build working again by editing the file:

```
D:\boost\boost_1_59_0\tools\build\src\tools\msvc.jam
```

I made two changes:

1. Change this (lines #1351-1355):

   ```
        generators.register [ new msvc-linking-generator msvc.link.dll :
            OBJ SEARCHED_LIB STATIC_LIB IMPORT_LIB : SHARED_LIB IMPORT_LIB :
            <toolset>msvc <suppress-import-lib>false ] ;
        generators.register [ new msvc-linking-generator msvc.link.dll :
            OBJ SEARCHED_LIB STATIC_LIB IMPORT_LIB : SHARED_LIB :
            <toolset>msvc <suppress-import-lib>true ] ;
   ```

   to:

   ```
       generators.register [ new msvc-linking-generator msvc.link.dll :
           OBJ SEARCHED_LIB STATIC_LIB IMPORT_LIB : SHARED_LIB IMPORT_LIB :
           <toolset>msvc ] ;
   ```
2. Remove this line (#1472):

   ```
       toolset.flags msvc.link.dll LINKFLAGS <suppress-import-lib>true : /NOENTRY ;
   ```

I've tested this on Win7 with VS2012 and Python 2.7.

Comment: I can confirm that current `boost 1.62` has the same issue. This fix is working (tested on _Windows 10_ with `msvc-12` and `python-3.4`).

Answer (score 1):

Madness I tell you.

Anyway, I finally succeeded in building the quickstart example on boost_1_68_0.
A quick guidethrough:

- (On windows, visual studio 2017 and SDK installed, python 3.5 installed)
- Download and extract it in like C:\boost_1_68_0
- Run bootstrap.bat
- Build the boost-python libraries:

> C:\boost_1_68_0>.\b2 --with-python -j4

- Go to C:\boost_1_68_0\libs\python\example, and fix the Jamroot to find your header files

```html
    project
  : requirements
    <include>C:\\boost_1_68_0
    <library>boost_python
```

- Fix the tools\build\src\tools\msvc.jam file in the way Ralph in this post commented
- As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362923/boost-python-class-export-fails-to-compile-with-linking-error-in-visual-studio-2) , patch embedding.cpp and extending.cpp by adding "#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB" as the first line everywhere
- Copy the built python-boost libs (from C:\boost_1_68_0\stage\lib) to the quickstart folder
- Finally build it

> C:\boost_1_68_0\libs\python\example\quickstart>..\..\..\..\b2.exe -j4

Again, this is -crazy- complex. All the other stuff builds just fine, but the python linkage is really broken. Anyway, in case anyone tries, hope this helps.